# Restore AWS RDS Database with memory optimized Filegroup in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

Can't restore AWS RDS database that has memory-optimized data.

I have a backup in S3 and when I try to do a restore into RDS:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database
    @restore_db_name='MyDatabase',
    @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/myBackup.bak'
```

it fails with:

```
RESTORE requires MAXTRANSFERSIZE=327680 but 65536 was specified. 
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally. 
Aborted the task because of a task failure or a concurrent RESTORE_DB request. 
Task has been aborted 
Empty restore file list result retrieved.
```

which makes some sense because as stated in: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

> When creating backups by using the SQL Writer Service, if the database has configured FILESTREAM, or includes memory optimized filegroups, then the MAXTRANSFERSIZE at the time of a restore should be greater than or equal to the MAXTRANSFERSIZE that was used when the backup was created.

But I've backed up the database originally with:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDatabase] 
   TO DISK = 'C:\Data\Backups\MyBackup.bak'
   WITH INIT, MAXTRANSFERSIZE = 65536, STATS = 1;
```

Is there a way to restore this database? the "RDS command" `msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database` doesn't allow me to specify a MAXTRANSFERSIZE parameter.